# Quintuple pawns / Interesting pawn structures

Tags: history, pawn-structure, famous-games

I played a game with an amateur that resulted in my opponent having tripled pawns right beside my doubled pawns.

[image: Picture of my game]

I'm wondered if there were any games with quadruple pawns. After finding such games, I started thinking of the possibility of quintuple pawns (high level preferably). Are there any games with such pawn structures, or generally any interesting pawn structures as seen in the above picture? Also, as a side question, what are your picks on the weirdest and most interesting pawn structures in a game you've played/found?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Tim Krabbé, [Kovacs - Barth, Balatonbereny 1994](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/recordstxt.htm#Longest%20living%20quadrupled%20pawns) was the game with the longest living quadrupled pawns (23 moves). That would imply that he (an authority when it comes to chess records) doesn't know of any games with quintupled pawns.

Answer (score 12):

[Wikipedia mentions Alekhine-Nenarokov 1907 and van der Wiel-Hort 1981](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubled_pawns#Tripled_and_quadrupled_pawns) as two (and by no means the only) games with quadrupled pawns. I can find no mention of quintupled pawns.

Comment: The former is at [chessgames](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1011704). The players and year 1907 match the alleged attribution in a spurious game, but the A-N here is a genuine game.

Answer (score 3):

I once had this position in one of my games as White:

```
r3qrk1/1bp3np/p3p3/1p1pPpp1/3b1P2/2PBP2P/PP4PB/R2Q1RK1 w - - 0 20

1. exd4 (1. cxd4)
```

I played exd4, undoubling my pawns, but also considered cxd4, which would have resulted in a picturesque "pawn diamond". Stockfish gives nearly the same evaluation to both moves, so maybe I should have gone with the diamond just so I could said I really played it instead of almost played it! :-)